# How to convert Image URL to ImageStream ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was doing this for local image

```
var imgstream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\TheSarfaraz\Downloads\SampleFacebookApp\SampleFacebookApp\SampleFacebookApp\Content\images\dreams-facebook-cover_4173.jpg");
```

But its not letting me do this for image URL

If I try this

```
var imgstream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"http://www.trendycovers.com/covers/Listen_to_your_heart_facebook_cover_1330517429.jpg?i");
```

I'm getting this error

```
URI formats are not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't ask for a web resource, such as image, to be treated as a regular file and to use I/O operations, such as `FileStream`, on it.

In your case, you should use the `WebClient` class which is using the HTTP GET method in order to download the image properly.

For example:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile(@"http://www.trendycovers.com/covers/Listen_to_your_heart_facebook_cover_1330517429.jpg?i", "Listen_to_your_heart_facebook_cover_1330517429.jpg");
}
```

The image file will be downloaded to your application folder unless you declare absolute path in the second parameter (`fileName`), such as: `c:\images\Listen_to_your_heart_facebook_cover_1330517429.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong class. You can not read a file from a webserver with the `File.OpenRead` function because this is not designed for that purpose. Try the WebClient.OpenRead function instead.